# getting Forbidden by robots.txt: scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

while crawling website like https://www.netflix.com, getting Forbidden by robots.txt: https://www.netflix.com/>

ERROR: No response downloaded for: https://www.netflix.com/

Comment: Robots.txt is just a text file that the robots respect, it cannot forbid you from doing anything. Netflix has probably other obstacles for scraping.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

In the new version (scrapy 1.1) launched 2016-05-11 the crawl first downloads robots.txt before crawling. To change this behavior change in your `settings.py` with [ROBOTSTXT_OBEY](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Here are the [release notes](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/news.html#id7)

Answer (score 4):

Netflix's Terms of Use state:

> You also agree not to circumvent, remove, alter, deactivate, degrade or thwart any of the content protections in the Netflix service; use any robot, spider, scraper or other automated means to access the Netflix service;

They have their robots.txt set up to block web scrapers. If you override the setting in `settings.py` to `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` then you are violating their terms of use which can result in a law suit.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to ensure is that you change your user agent in the request, otherwise default user agent will be blocked for sure.

Comment: how do you change your user agent?