# What robots.txt means in this line?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape some data from a website which robots.txt file contain this, is not this means I can scrape from anywhere but wp-admin ?
Also is there any other way from which I can know that website allow scraping/crawling without any blocking ?
For scraping I use Python Scrapy Framework.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Comment: Checking the `robots.txt` is always a good way to see if you're allowed to scrape. I would check the TOS and EULA as well. Yes, that is what the `robots.txt` means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274835/getting-forbidden-by-robots-txt-scrapy/37278895#37278895

Comment: I have not any idea about TOS and EULA, Would u please give any link or a little details, thanks a lot! @MorganThrapp

Comment: The terms of service and end user license agreement. It's going to vary from site to site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a newer version of Scrapy, new settings variable is introduced `robotstxt_obey` - which will follow the robots txt strictly if enabled

bu default it has value `True`

As mentioned in comment,doc does say default value is `False` but this behavior was changed in latest version of scrapy and now defaults to `True`

- [Closed PR - Changed ROBOTSTXT_OBEY default from False to True](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1867)
- [Open PR for change in Doc for the same](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2308)
- [Link To scrapy docs - robotstxt-obey](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)

Comment: Didn't know that, and the value is set to True! I've not changed it. It was this way . thanks

Comment: Yes, the value defaults to True for every new scrapy project created via `scrapy startproject` since the recent scrapy versions.

Comment: yes , Now it does default to """ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True""", and doc doesn't reflect the latest change, have raised PR on Github project for the same